# Compression of an image

Tags: compression, rgb, pixel, image-compression

I have been calculating the uncompressed and compressed file sizes of an image. This for me has always resulted in the compressed image being smaller than the uncompressed image which I would expect. If an image contains a large number of different colours, then storing the palette takes up a significant amount of space, and more bits are also needed to store each code. However my question is, would it be possible the compression method could potentially result in a larger file than the uncompressed RGB image. What would the size (in pixels) of the smallest square RGB image, containing a total of k different colours, for which this compression method is still useful? So we want to find, for a given value of k, find the smallest integer number n for which an image of size n×n takes up less storage space after compression than the original RGB image.

Comment: we want to check that a compressed image of size n × n with k different colours takes up less storage than the uncompressed image, and  a compressed image of size (n − 1) × (n − 1) with k different colours takes up more storage than the uncompressed image.

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin by making a small simplification -- the size of the encoded output depends on the number of pixels (the actual proportion of width vs. height doesn't really matter). Hence, let's generalize the problem to number of pixels **N**, from which we can always calculate **n** by taking a square root.

[image: <code>N = n \times n \ \text{pixels}</code>]

To further simplify the problem, we will also ignore the overhead of any image headers/metadata, such as width, height, size of the palette, etc. In practice, this would generally be some relatively small constant.

---

#### Problem Statement

Given that we have

- **N** representing the number of pixels in an image
- **k** representing the number of distinct colours in an image
- **24** bits per pixel RGB encoding
- **L<sub>RGB</sub>** representing the length of a RGB image
- **L<sub>P</sub>** representing the length of a palette image

our goal is to solve the following inequality

[image: <code>L_{\text{RGB}} > L_{\text{P}}</code>]

in terms of **N**.

---

#### Size of RGB Image

RGB image is just an array of **N** pixels, each pixel taking up a fixed number of bits given by the RGB encoding. Hence,

[image: <code>L_{\text{RGB}} = \left( N \times 24 \right) \ \text{bits}</code>]

---

#### Size of Palette Image

Palette image consists of two parts: a palette, and the pixels.

[image: <code>L_{\text{P}} = L_{\text{palette}} + L_{\text{pixels}}</code>]

A palette is an array of **k** colours, each colour taking up a fixed number of bits given by the RGB encoding. Therefore,

[image: <code>L_{\text{palette}} = \left( k \times 24 \right) \ \text{bits}</code>]

In this case, each pixel holds an index to a palette entry, rather than an actual RGB colour. The number of bits required to represent **k** values is

[image: <code>\log_{2}{k} \ \text{bits}</code>]

However, unless we can encode fractional bits (which I consider outside the scope of this question), we need to round this up. Therefore, the number of bits required to encode a palette index is

[image: <code>\left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \ \text{bits}</code>]

Since there are **N** such palette indices, the size of the pixel data is

[image: <code>L_{\text{pixels}} = \left( N \times \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \right) \ \text{bits}</code>]

and the total size of the palette image is

[image: <code>L_{\text{P}} = \left( k \times 24 \right) + \left( N \times \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \right) \ \text{bits}</code>]

---

#### Solving the Inequality

[image: <code>L_{\text{RGB}} > L_{\text{P}}</code>]

[image: <code>\left( N \times 24 \right) > \left( k \times 24 \right) + \left( N \times \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \right)</code>]

[image: <code>\left( N \times 24 \right) - \left( N \times \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \right) > \left( k \times 24 \right)</code>]

[image: <code>\left( N \times \left( 24 - \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil \right) \right) > \left( k \times 24 \right)</code>]

And finally

[image: <code>N > \frac{k \times 24}{24 - \left \lceil{\log_{2}{k}}\right \rceil}</code>]

---

In Python, we could express this in the following way:

```
import math

def limit_size(k):
    return (k * 24.) / (24. - math.ceil(math.log(k, 2)))

def size_rgb(N):
    return (N * 24.)

def size_pal(N, k):
    return (N * math.ceil(math.log(k, 2))) + (k * 24.)
```

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Mathsstudent Let's start with base 10 -- 1 digit number can represent 10 (=10^1) different values. 2 digit number can represent 100 (=10^2) values. 3 digit number can represent 1000 (=10^3) values. See the pattern? We can generalize this as **n**-digit number in base 10 can represent 10^n different values. Base 2 follows similar pattern - 2, 4, 8, .... -> 2^n. | To answer the question "how many digits do I need", we know the number of values, and we want to find the n (the exponent). The inverse of exponentiation is [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), so that's what we use..

Comment: ok I understand thanks. how does the formula you gave relate to checking that a compressed image of size n × n with k different colours takes up less storage than the uncompressed image, and a compressed image of size (n − 1) × (n − 1) with k different colours takes up more storage than the uncompressed image.

Comment: @Mathsstudent Let's say **k=16**. Plug that into the inequality and you get **N > 19.2**. Since we're looking for a square image, we take square root of that: n > 4.38. Next larger integer is 5, so for 5x5 RGB is larger (600 vs 484 bits), and for 4x4 compressed is larger (384 vs 448).

Answer (score 0):

In general no, but your question is not precise.

If we compress normal files, they could be larger. E.g. if you compress a random generated sequence of bytes, there is not much to compress, and so you get the header of compression program, which tell which compression method is used, and some versioning. This will enlarge the file, and ev. some escaping.  Good compression program will see that compression will not shrink the size, and so they should just not compress, and tell in the header that it is a flat file. Possibly this is done by region of program.

But your question is about images. Compression is done inside the file, and often not all file, but just the image bits. In this case program will see that there is no need to compress, and so they would keep the file uncompressed. But because the image headers are always present, this change only a flag, and so no increase of size.

But this could depends also on file format. You wrote about "palette", but this is not much used nowadays: compression is done finding similar pattern on file. But again: this depends on the image format.  If you look in Wikipedia, for particular file format, you may see a table with headers parameters (e.g. bit depth or number of colours (palette), definitions of colours, and methods used to compress).

Then, for palette like image, the answer of Dan Mašek (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683948/2758823) has some nice mathematical explanation, but one should not forget that compression is much heuristic and test of real examples: real images have patterns.